# How to write an extension to close tabs on "back" attempt when there's no previous page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I find myself more and more using the touchpad gesture of 3 fingers to the left or right in order to perform a "back" or "forward" in Google Chrome (on my Asus Zenbook, but I believe there's a similar gesture on Macs)

I found that when browsing, I open a tab to read something (Like a like from Twitter or Facebook) and when I'm done my instinct is to go "back" to get back to the previous tab I was browsing on. (I think I got that instinct from using Android a lot).

I figured that I need a Chrome extension that would close my current tab if I'm attempting to go "back" in a tab that doesn't have a previous page in its history.

I went over the Chrome events and various methods I can invoke and while there's a "forward_back" transition qualifier in the WebNavigation api, the onCommitted event doesn't fire when attempting to go "back" using the touchpad gesture or Alt+left keyboard shortcut.

Also, I couldn't find how I can access a current tab's history to see if the page I'm at doesn't have a previous one in the stack.

Ideas anyone?

```
function noHistory(tabId) {
    // TODO
}

function getCurrentTabId() {
    // TODO
}

function userHitBack() {
    tabId = getCurrentTabId();
    if (noHistory(tabId)) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId)   
    }
}

function attachEvent() {
    // TODO attach userHitBack
}

attachEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

To catch the "back" event, you need to handle specific key pressed to call your "userHitBack" function. Something like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if (keyId == ...)
        userHitBack()
}
```

You can use this to your advantage as you can bind any key to trigger the close of the tab.

To check the tab history length use this:

```
window.history.length
```

It is html5 historyAPI

Comment: If I wanted to use the keyboard to close the tab I would just press ctrl+w, the point is to detect the "3 finger swipe" left.
I do you think the "3 finger swipe" has a keyId?

Comment: Hi, sorry, i misunderstood the question. Thought you want smt like Alt left keyboard short cut.